# Change cell background color in FMX TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Here is a form with a `TStringGrid` component containing 2 `TStringColumn` columns, a button and an edit box. Clicking on the button should change the contents of one cell and its background color, the color of a column and the color of the edit box. The cell text is updated and formatted correctly and the color of the edit box is changed fine but the color of the cell does not change, nor does the color of the column.

I believe I've followed all the previous tips from Ray Konopka and Mike Sutton ...
Can anyone tell me why parts of this code do not work?

I am aware that the code may well not compile with later versions of FireMonkey.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Grid, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Objects,
  FMX.Edit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    StringColumn1: TStringColumn;
    StringColumn2: TStringColumn;

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rect: TRectangle;
  cell: TTextCell;
  text: string;
begin

// Select a cell in column 1
  cell:= stringColumn1.CellControlByRow(3) as TTextCell;

// Enter some text in cell
  text:= 'hello sailor';
  cell.TextAlign:= TTextAlign.taCenter;
  cell.Text:= text;             // works fine

// Change cell background color
  rect:= cell.FindStyleResource('background') as TRectangle;
  if rect <> nil then
    rect.Fill.Color:= claRed;   // does nothing

// Change color of all cells in grid
  rect:= stringGrid1.FindStyleResource('background') as TRectangle;
  if rect <> nil then
    rect.Fill.Color:= claBisque; // works fine

// Change color of all cells in column 2
  rect:= stringColumn2.FindStyleResource('background') as TRectangle;
  if rect <> nil then
    rect.Fill.Color:= claGreen;  // does nothing

// Change background color of edit box
  rect:= edit1.FindStyleResource('background') as TRectangle;
  if rect <> nil then
    rect.Fill.Color:= claBlue;   // works fine
end;

end.
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code you've provided? Set a breakpoint on the `rect` assignment before the code you say doesn't work, and step through that line (using F8 when the breakpoint is hit). What is the value of `rect` at that point?

Comment: rect = nil at that line

Comment: Bear in mind that styles can be dynamically lookup-ed and freed, so any custom styling will need to hook into the style lookup mechanism, and to get to that you need to get to the cell creation code, which is not accessible in a TStringGrid. In short: stick with plain TGrids if you want custom cells/columns.

Comment: Also, if you follow Ken's advice you'll probably find the background is a TSubImage in all the default system styles. If so you'll either want a custom style to replace the TSubImage with a TRectangle, or add some extra images to the style and modify the TTextCellStyle.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I've realised now that TStringGrid is fairly limited and that TGrid is a lot more configurable - further to reading your article on monkeystyler.com. Secondly, I should have specified in my question that I'm using XE2 and TSubImage only appears as a subclass of FMX.Objects in XE3 onwards so this is not available to me. Thanks once again for your help.